# MySQL 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I need some help in this SQL Code. I am new to SQL and using the Sams Teach Yourself SQL.

```
   INSERT INTO `eli`.`checks`
(`check`,
`payee`,
`amount`,
`remarks`)
VALUES
(500,'John Dree',450.00,'Bills');
INSERT INTO `eli`.`checks`
(`check`,
`payee`,
`amount`,
`remarks`)
VALUES
(575,'Ma Belle',150.00,'Gas Bills');
INSERT INTO `eli`.`checks`
(`check`,
`payee`,
`amount`,
`remarks`)
VALUES
(600,'Jon Cash',350.00,'Shopping');
```

I am getting error 1064: . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'payee, amount, reINSERT INTO eli`.checks' at line 1

[image]
Thank you :)

Comment: This means that there is already a record in your `checks` table with the value of `19200` for your `check` field and you can't insert duplicates.

Comment: I change the value to 4, still getting error for Duplicate

Comment: Good news it passed when I did it to 100

Comment: Your `check` field is your `primary key`.  It cannot already exist.  So if `4` exists in that table, you'll get the same error.

Comment: Now -_- I am getting error 1064: . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`payee`, `amount`, `reINSERT INTO `eli`.`checks`' at line 1

Comment: So what wrong now? @sgeddes

Comment: My guess is you're not running the correct `sql`.  Your comment says `reINSERT INTO` -- that's not valid syntax...  Edit your question and post what you're attempting to run...  Did you perhaps miscopy and paste?

Comment: Please, put you table structure too.

Comment: Error is comprehensive even if you have never used MySQL. You can't have two records that have same primary key. You're trying to do exactly that. Fix #1 - don't do it. Fix #2 - choose a better primary key. Usually when people ask for help, they include everything they can to help others help them. You haven't done that.

Comment: ok I added a screenshot

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, please copy/paste in the exact code as you are currently trying to execute it and getting the syntax error.

Comment: That is the code I am running

Comment: Should I upload the project

Comment: Your check column has an extra space between the back tick and check.I`m assuming your column name does not start with an empty space.

Comment: That error in your screen shot did *not* come from that code.  Duplicate entry `100` -- you're not inserting `100`... Open a new query window and try again...

Comment: The error looks like a faulty text selection was executed (attempted execution) by MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, I really appreciate you guys taking your time to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
INSERT INTO `eli`.`checks` (`check`, `payee`, `amount`, `remarks`) VALUES
(500, 'John Dree', 450.00, 'Bills'),
(575, 'Ma Belle', 150.00, 'Gas Bills'),
(600, 'Jon Cash', 350.00, 'Shopping');
```

Comment: I verified your query it should work but usually I am lazy so I write it the way mentioned above to save time so I can simply focus on the data and not rewriting the insert part of the query.